# Multiple desktops on multiple displays in Windows 10

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, virtual-desktop

At my desk, I have a second monitor plugged into my laptop. When I unplug it and go away, all the windows on the second display get crammed onto my laptop screen.

I would like to have that second display be represented as a virtual desktop instead so that when the monitor is plugged in I can see both desktops at the same time and when it is not I can switch between them using task view.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is evidently [possible using DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/windows-10-issue-virtual-desktops-and-additional-monitorstaskbars/?ID=b9cd43cd-128c-4dfd-adf6-26dfd980cef7) as a side effect of a bug.

([Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/multiple-monitors-and-virtual-desktops-in-windows/6dfff267-ede5-474a-a0bc-ea868eafaeb7))