# Two Monitors, Two Desktops nativelly?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, multiple-desktop

Windows 10 supports multiple desktops (Win + Tab) but is it possible to set one desktop to each monitor nativelly?

I use a laptop with a external monitor and would like if each screen worked as a independent desktop. What happens is that I`m switching between desktops (Ctlr + Win + left/right) and it is switching on both screens.

Comment: Related/Possible Dupe: [Multiple desktops on multiple displays in Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/950112/multiple-desktops-on-multiple-displays-in-windows-10?rq=1)

Comment: If you're going to include the caveat of "natively" then the answer is No, Windows 10 doesn't support this (yet?).

Comment: I use the software Dexpot to do this. When I upgraded to Windows 10 I thought that I woudn't need it anymore. Thank you.

Comment: You should answer this question OP with your solution, or by saying that it is not possible.

Comment: Wow so Windows doesn't support this.